# Is Yucca plant dead?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, pruning, plant-recommendations, repotting

[image]I bought my Yucca plant in February and it was fine. I believe I might have over watered it. Recently I saw the leaves turning yellow, I decided to re-pot it with cactus  soil and one spray of plant food. I added a small amount of water to soil so  it’s  not completely dry.  The plant really started to die after, a lot of it’s leaves started to dry out and I was left with very few.  Then I noticed they all wilted none of them spiked up anymore, but they were still very green.  I decided to re pot it again but cutting the trunk and getting rid of the rotten roots.  When I cut the trunk the middle feels it has moisture.  Is this Yucca plant worth saving? 
[image]

Comment: I also forgot to mention the branches at the top are very mushy and break easily and is not sturdy,  but the trunk is still very firm?

Comment: Nice photos. You can edit your question to put the comment info there. And Welcome.